# Websocket closing unexpectedly when saving an audio file

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="generateAudio()">Generate Audio</button>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <script>
        var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8765');

        function generateAudio() {
            websocket.send('generate_audio');
        }

        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            document.getElementById('message').textContent = event.data;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from gtts import gTTS
import os

async def generate_audio(websocket, path):
    
        await websocket.send('Audio file generation started')
        tts = gTTS(text='Hello, world!', lang='en')
        filename = 'hello.mp3'
        tts.save(filename)
        await websocket.send('Audio file generated')

start_server = websockets.serve(generate_audio, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

when the script gets to the part where the audio file is supposed to be saved, I believe it closes the websocket connection which isn't supposed to happen. It doesn't give an error when saving the video, it doesn't have anything to do with the time because other parts of the script take a while and they work and I am running it in it's own thread.

this is most of the relevant parts of the script. the issue with file saving is in the function speech (which is defined above)

```
sorry if my code is sloppy, I have been working on this project and expanding it since I was a lot less experienced with coding (I am still pretty new). also sorry if I didn't post this right it is my first time.



It should continue running the script and sending messages to the web end however upon getting to the line that saves the audio file it closes the connection
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).